# I am trying to load a fragment but the app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to get a fragment to load when an item in a list is clicked. The item text is "Nutrient/Target calculator." The program crashes when I click on the list item in the MainActivity.java file.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.crims.fooddiarytools;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity  extends ListActivity {

    private ListViewCustomAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(this);
        mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem("Food");
        mAdapter.addItem("Nutrient/Target calculator");


        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String itemInList = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


                if(itemInList.equals("Nutrient/Target calculator")) {
                    // this won't load it crashes //////////////////////////////
                    Fragment fragment = new NutrientTargetCalculator();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    ft.replace(android.R.id.list, fragment);
                    ft.commit();
                }

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), itemInList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mAdapter.myCliquedPosition = position;
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

NutrientTargetCalculator.java

```
package com.example.crims.fooddiarytools;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NutrientTargetCalculator extends Fragment{

    private static Button buttonNutrient;
    private static Button  buttonNutrientTarget;
    private static Spinner foodUnitSpinner;
    private static Spinner foodNutrientsSpinner;
    private static TextView editTextNutrients;
    private static TextView editTextServingSize;
    private static TextView editTextScaleWeight;
    private static TextView editTextNutrientOutput;
    private static TextView editTextNutrientTarget;
    private static TextView textViewServingOutPut1;

    View myView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nutrient_target_calculator, container, false);
        return myView;
    }

}
```

ListViewCustomAdapter.java

```
package com.example.crims.fooddiarytools;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 * Created by crims on 12/22/2016.
 */

public class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public int myCliquedPosition;

    public ListViewCustomAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSectionHeaderItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        sectionHeader.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
        public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (rowType) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_text, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_box, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
  12-22 23:36:43.716 4518-4518/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
    12-22 23:36:43.922 4518-4518/com.example.crims.testing W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.crims.testing-1/lib/x86
    12-22 23:36:43.926 4518-4518/com.example.crims.testing I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.crims.testing, real application class is null.
    12-22 23:36:45.027 4518-4518/com.example.crims.testing W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.crims.testing-1/lib/x86
    12-22 23:36:45.257 4518-4518/com.example.crims.testing W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    12-22 23:36:45.556 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
    12-22 23:36:45.612 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    12-22 23:36:45.673 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing E/EGL_emulation: tid 4542: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
    12-22 23:36:45.673 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa413620, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
    12-22 23:37:06.989 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae4710e0
    12-22 23:37:10.167 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing E/EGL_emulation: tid 4542: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
    12-22 23:37:10.167 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa413620, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
    12-22 23:38:40.868 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa1d5170
    12-22 23:38:45.673 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing E/EGL_emulation: tid 4542: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
    12-22 23:38:45.673 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa413620, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
    12-22 23:40:15.359 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae4710e0
    12-22 23:40:44.665 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing E/EGL_emulation: tid 4542: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
    12-22 23:40:44.665 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa413620, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
    12-22 23:43:30.414 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae4710e0
    12-22 23:43:34.790 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing E/EGL_emulation: tid 4542: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
    12-22 23:43:34.790 4518-4542/com.example.crims.testing W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa413620, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

Comment: Where does the app crash? Add the stacktrace

Comment: Post the error log

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @mlidal I posted the output. I believe(I am new to android programming)

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' I posted the output I believe(I am new to Android)

Comment: this is not the entire stackTrace, the crash might be throwing some Exception, find that in stacktrace

Comment: @crims I think you are trying to add the fragment to the listView. This doesn't work, you should create your own layout for the activity which contains listView and a fragment container(like LinearLayout) and add the fragment to the fragment conatiner (when clicked on item hide the listview)

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' Okay thank you.Someone left a comment and I am starting to understand the problem. As stated, I am new to Android.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot replace the **android.R.id.list**. Use this steps:

1. extend Activity, not ListActivity
2. Create custom layout in res/layouts that will have one LinearLayout with some id (ex. list_wrapper) and in that LinearLayout one listview with some id (ex. calc_listview)
3. Use that calc_listview instead of android.R.id.list
4. Replace

> ft.replace(android.R.id.list, fragment);

with

> ft.replace(R.id.list_wrapper, fragment);

Comment: I did exactly what you said. It is crashed on lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() class.